# cs50 runoff infinite loop

Tags: c, loops, cs50

There is this exercise of cs50 that we have to make a runoff election then print the winner when somebody it has more than 50% of all votes. so, to make the election running while the winner can't be found, it has a while loop which always return true until the "print_winner()" function break it. but even when I make the function print_winner and the candidate has more than 50% of votes, the loop doesn't stop.

at first (when the print_winner() function wasn't ready) I tried to look at all my code and see if there is some error, but I can't find it then I realize that I need make the print_winner() function at least, but, even when the function its complete, it doesn't work.

So, I want to know if it's normal because the code isn't all ready or if it's a real bug.

And, if it's a real bug, where should I look to fix it?

Here's the code:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

// Max voters and candidates
#define MAX_VOTERS 100 // constante MAX de eleitores = 100
#define MAX_CANDIDATES 9 // constante MAX de candidatos = 9

// preferences[i][j] is jth preference for voter i
int preferences[MAX_VOTERS][MAX_CANDIDATES];

// Candidates have name, vote count, eliminated status
typedef struct
{
    string name;
    int votes;
    bool eliminated;
}
candidate;

// Array of candidates
candidate candidates[MAX_CANDIDATES];

// Numbers of voters and candidates
int voter_count;
int candidate_count;

// Function prototypes
bool vote(int voter, int rank, string name);
void tabulate(void);
bool print_winner(void);
int find_min(void);
bool is_tie(int min);
void eliminate(int min);

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    // Check for invalid usage
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: runoff [candidate ...]\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Populate array of candidates
    candidate_count = argc - 1;
    if (candidate_count > MAX_CANDIDATES)
    {
        printf("Maximum number of candidates is %i\n", MAX_CANDIDATES);
        return 2;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++) // loop que add os candidatos na array candidate
    {
        candidates[i].name = argv[i + 1];
        candidates[i].votes = 0;
        candidates[i].eliminated = false;
    }

    voter_count = get_int("Number of voters: ");
    if (voter_count > MAX_VOTERS)
    {
        printf("Maximum number of voters is %i\n", MAX_VOTERS);
        return 3;
    }

    // Keep querying for votes
    for (int i = 0; i < voter_count; i++) // i ira gerar a quantidade de vezes que o loop j   sera iniciado
    {

        // Query for each rank
        for (int j = 0; j < candidate_count; j++)
        {
            string name = get_string("Rank %i: ", j + 1);

            // Record vote, unless it's invalid
            if (!vote(i, j, name))
            {
                printf("Invalid vote.\n");
                return 4;
            }
        }

        printf("\n");
    }

    // Keep holding runoffs until winner exists
    while (true)
    {
        // Calculate votes given remaining candidates
        tabulate();

        // Check if election has been won
        bool won = print_winner();
        if (won)
        {
            break;
        }

        // Eliminate last-place candidates
        int min = find_min();
        bool tie = is_tie(min);

        // If tie, everyone wins
        if (tie)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
            {
                if (!candidates[i].eliminated)
                {
                    printf("%s\n", candidates[i].name);
                }
            }
            break;
        }

        // Eliminate anyone with minimum number of votes
        eliminate(min);

        // Reset vote counts back to zero
        for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
        {
            candidates[i].votes = 0;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

// Record preference if vote is valid
bool vote(int voter, int rank, string name)
{
    // TODO
    for (int i = 0; i < voter_count; i++) //passa por todos os eleitores
    {
        if (strcmp(name, candidates[i].name) == 0) // compara os nomes
        {
            preferences[voter][rank] = i; // preferences[eleitor 0][1° opçao 0] = candidato
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}


// Tabulate votes for non-eliminated candidates
void tabulate(void)
{
    // TODO

    // mede o tamanho da array
    int lenght = sizeof(preferences) / sizeof(preferences[0]);

    for (int i = 0; i < voter_count; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < candidate_count; j++)
        {
            if (candidates[preferences[i][j]].eliminated == false)
            {
                break;
            }
            else if (candidates[preferences[i][j]].eliminated == true)
            {
                candidates[preferences[i][j + 1]].votes++;
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
     } 

return;
}

// Print the winner of the election, if there is one
bool print_winner(void)
{
    // TODO
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        if (candidates[i].votes > (voter_count / 2))
        {
            printf("%s\n", candidates[i].name);
            return true;
            break;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

// Return the minimum number of votes any remaining candidate has
int find_min(void)
{
    // TODO
    return 0;
}

// Return true if the election is tied between all candidates, false otherwise
bool is_tie(int min)
{
    // TODO
    return false;
}

// Eliminate the candidate (or candidates) in last place
void eliminate(int min)
{
    // TODO
    return;
}
```

Comment: Your code `bool won = print_winner(); if (won) { break; }` breaks the loop when the `print_winner()` function returns true, which is the opposite of what you said in the blurb for your question.

Comment: You need to implement `eliminate`, `is_tie`, and `find_min` to prevent the loop in print_winner. Without those functions, nothing changes (no candidate is ever eliminated) therefore the vote counts don't change,

Comment: @JonathanLeffler thank you! I was trying to understand the previous code to get what I should do, but I didn't get that and it makes me confused.

Comment: @DinoCoderSaurus I am grateful! I was very confused because the previous code wasn't written by me, so it was hard for me to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The infinite loop at that moment was **normal** because the code wasn't ready yet. The functions *find_min*, *is_Tie*, and *eliminate* needed to be completed for the program to run without any error.

But why? In the previous code, the functions *find_min*, *is_Tie*, and *eliminate* are in a **loop that will only be broken if they get a winner**. The code can't return a winner when they can't calculate all of the votes, eliminate all of them who don't have more than 50% of all votes, or check if it's a tie.

```
    // Keep holding runoffs until winner exists
while (true)
{
    // Calculate votes given remaining candidates
    tabulate();

    // Check if election has been won
    bool won = print_winner();
    if (won)
    {
        break;
    }

    // Eliminate last-place candidates
    int min = find_min();
    bool tie = is_tie(min);

    // If tie, everyone wins
    if (tie)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
        {
            if (!candidates[i].eliminated)
            {
                printf("%s\n", candidates[i].name);
            }
        }
        break;
    }

    // Eliminate anyone with minimum number of votes
    eliminate(min);

    // Reset vote counts back to zero
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        candidates[i].votes = 0;
    }
}
```